# Does speaking to self, use different area of brain as opposed to speaking to a person?

Tags: neuroscience, communication

When speaking without the intent of communicating, but just to ones self or reading to ones self. Does this use a different area of the brain as opposed to speaking to a person, or even a device such as Alexa?

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  I actually think this question is a duplicate of https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/15327/7001 - the answer is: "no - it uses the same part of the brain."  Do you agree that this question is already answered there?